# Display DataGridView Rows Based on Similar ID

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have this sample table, and working in C# Form Creator Microsoft Visual Studio 2017:

[image]

This is my code to add all the rows to the datagridview.

```
string filename = theDialog.FileName;
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filename);
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
string[] columnnames = file.ReadLine().Split('|');
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (string c in columnnames)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(c);
}
string newline;
while ((newline = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    string[] values = newline.Split('|');
    for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        dr[i] = values[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

My question is:
1) How to show data that have the same ID, for example based on the table above, only show rows that have ID 111 and then when the user clicks a button next, it will go to the next ID which is 222?

Thank you in advance

Comment: once you load the Datatable.. you can use the `.Select()` method to query for the particular Id's you are looking for.. you would need to look at using the `DataView.Select` method

Comment: You could just apply a RowFilter

Comment: @Plutonix any tips on implementing it in the Next button method? So whenever I click next, it will go to the next ID?

Comment: @MethodMan do you know how I can select the next ID? because i cant just do a select... where id=111

Comment: Yes by RowFiltering.. do a google search

Comment: @MethodMan i have done the filter which dv.RowFilter = "ID = '111'"; but  do you know how to make it go to the next available ID?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below.  I think this will do exactly what you want.  It does take a little work to get it up and running, so keep at it, if it doesn't work on the first try.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs

[image]

[image]